# Why do we subtract the velocity of the gun barrel to find the velocity of bullet in classic gun barrel problems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

The very subtle conceptual problem I'm having is that assuming the gun barrel is at rest...and then it fires the bullet by means of an mini explosion of gunpowder let's say then it is delivering the force of the explosion to both the gun barrel and bullet simultaneously. Thus the velocity obtained by the bullet should be completely given by the explosion of gunpowder. Then why do we subtract the velocity vector of barrel in order to find bullets velocity w.r.t ground?

Comment: We don't "minus the velocity vector of barrel...".  Linear momentum is universally conserved in a closed system.  Because of this there will be a recoil.  The sign comes out form the math.

Answer (score 2):

The clearest way to tackle this question is to remember that the momentum is always zero.

If the gun is floating in mid-air, then the total momentum of "gun plus bullet" is zero before the gun is fired and zero after the gun is fired.

*So if you know the forward velocity of the bullet,* you can multiply by the mass of the bullet to get the forward momentum of the bullet. This is the same as the backward momentum of the gun. Then you divide by the mass of the gun to get the backward velocity of the gun.

You **do not** subtract the backward velocity of the gun from the forward velocity of the bullet.

---

So what happens if the gun is heavier, or tied down firmly?

If you work out the velocities for gun and bullet, for different masses of gun - and if the gun is tied to a rock, the "mass" of the gun is the weight of the gun plus the mass of the rock - you find that the total kinetic energy after the explosion is $$\frac12(1+\frac m M)mv^2$$ where $m$ is the mass of the bullet, $M$ is the mass of the gun, and $v$ is the velocity of the bullet. (The velocity of the gun is deduced from these three numbers: it is not a separate variable).

The heavier the gun is, or the more solidly the gun is tied to a large heavy object (a rock, or even the whole Earth), the smaller $(1+\frac m M)$ will be, so that, for a fixed energy of explosion, $v$ will be larger.

The higher bullet velocity from a gun that is firmly fixed does not come from an extra "impulse" from the thing the gun is fixed to. It comes from a higher effective "mass" of the gun-plus-fixture.

Comment: @SujalPatel "if the gun barrel is inclined at 45 degrees to the horizontal,when the gun is fired the bullet will be fired at an angle greater than 45 degrees" It's unclear to me what you're saying there.  The bullet should go in the same direction as the gun barrel when fired.

Answer (score -4):

Because in accordance with Newton's 3rd Law of motion, the barrel recoils in the opposite direction to the shell or bullet. The faster the barrel recoils, the slower the bullet which comes out of the muzzle. The speed of the recoiling barrel varies tremendously, but it will be much slower than the bullet because it has much greater mass. There are various forms of recoil absorber which slow down the barrel's movement even further. I was once in charge of a 90mm anti-tank gun which was so firmly dug in that the barrel was unable to recoil at all, in which case it would have been unnecessary to subtract the velocity of the barrel from he velocity of the shell. High velocity is particularly desirable in the case of an anti-tank gun. And then there are recoilless rifles, which as the name suggests, don't recoil at all, in which case I suppose you'd have to subtract the velocity of the backblast gases which are ejected at very high speed in the opposite direction to the shell. Newton's 3rd Law has to be obeyed.

Comment: "The faster the barrel recoils, the slower the bullet which comes out of the muzzle." Isn't it the exact opposite?

Comment: Stand on a stationary skate board, then leap forward as fast as you can  The faster the skate board recoils In the opposite direction, the slower you move forward, Then get someone or something to hold the skate board down and prevent it moving. You will the find that the missile (you) will be propelled faster away rom the skate board than when it was allowed to recoil..

Comment: Conservation of momentum.  The faster your gun recoils backwards, the greater momentum you've given to the bullet+gas system forwards.  If I jump off a skateboard, assuming the same resisting forces; the further the skateboard goes the further I travel in the other direction.

Comment: Not compared to how far you would go if something stopped the skate board or the barrel moving or slowed it down. Having been in the Army, I've had quite a lot to do with guns.

Comment: Yes, as in a different resistive force.  That's because you put some of the momentum into something much more massive, like the ground.  The statement "The faster the barrel recoils, the slower the bullet which comes out of the muzzle" is still highly misleading on it's own like that; because all other things equal, a gun with more recoil means a faster bullet (which also means a gun that goes back faster, not slower).

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you look at my example of the 90mm gun barrel which didn't recoil at all, that meant the shell went faster, not slower.

Comment: Yes, and if you fired something from that exact same mounting, and when fired the gun _did_ move; then that projectile would be going faster than in the case where the gun didn't move.  Like I said, _all else equal_ the gun that moves back more will have a faster moving projectile in general, including the case of a large mounted gun.

Comment: @JMac is right. Your answer touts Newton's third law, yet you are applying it incorrectly.

Comment: He's not right. A charge large enough to cause the barrel of a 90mm gun to recoil when it was never designed to recoil would destroy the gun and probably kill the gunner. Having worked much of my life with guns, I know more about them than you ever will.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby You're _completely_ missing the point.  Yes, I'm aware a large gun isn't designed to, and thus shouldn't, move when fired.  That's irrelevant, I was just trying to use your example to show the point.  Instead, consider a handgun.  Assuming the the same gun being held, the one that gets pushed back with the greater force is also pushing the bullet forward with a greater force.  The greater push backwards makes it push backwards faster; therefore, it's trivial to show that the gun moving back faster means a faster bullet, all other things equal.

Comment: Some guns are designed to recoil, usually with some sort of recoil absorber mechanism, and some guns are not. Anti tank guns usually don't recoil, partly because that would reduce the velocity of the round. Trafalgar-type naval guns were allowed to recoil because gun design was primitive in those days, but large, modern naval guns don't recoil. They nevertheless have a much higher muzzle velocity than the old ones which did recoil.

Comment: _All_ guns have recoil.  That's a consequence of Newton's laws.  Some guns are designed to absorb that recoil through a mounted system which doesn't move relative to the ground. Instead, the whole ground + mount system moves; it's just so massive that the movement is totally negligible.  With two equivalent mounted guns, the gun+ground system which moves back faster will also be firing the projectile faster.  It's the same thing.  It only doesn't apply when you try to compare apples and oranges, like a handgun to a mounted gun.

Comment: You are talking about a subtly different system than @JMac is talking about. JMac recognizes this and is trying to show you how you are talking about different things. There is no reason to get heated over this. It seems like you both would agree if you were both on the same page.

Comment: The question was, why do we need to subtract the velocity of the barrel to find the (exact) velocity of the shell or bullet. I have given a clear and accurate answer, and if there were people not bright enough to understand it, that's not my fault.